# Issue with Service Timeout

Tags: web-services, cxf

I have generated the client stubs using WSDLToJava. After that I have created the client as mentioned here  http://cxf.apache.org/docs/developing-a-consumer.

```
this.testService = new TestService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME); //line #1
    this.port = testService.getTestPort();          //line #2
    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);        //line #3
    client.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
    client.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
    HTTPConduit conduit = (HTTPConduit)client.getConduit();
    // setting timeouts for connection
    String timeOutSecond = CoreProperty.getProp(CORE_SERVICE_TIME_OUT_MILLISECONDS);
    int timeout =0;
    try{
        if(Utils.isNotNullOrBlank(timeOutSecond))
            timeout = Integer.parseInt(timeOutSecond.trim());
        else
            timeout = Constants.DEFAULT_SERVICE_TIME_OUT_MILLISECONDS;
    }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        timeout = Constants.DEFAULT_SERVICE_TIME_OUT_MILLISECONDS;
    }
    conduit.getClient().setReceiveTimeout(timeout);
```

The issue is that line #1 is taking almost 5 minutes to throw error if the server is down - specified in the `wsdlURL` .

I want to set a time out of 30 seconds to establish the client connection.

If the service is up everything is working fine and the receivetimeout I have set working fine. How can I set the timeout for establishing the connection. 
**THE PROGRAM IS WAITING AT LINE #1 IF THE SERVER IS DOWN, IT IS WAITING FOR MORE THAN 4 MINUTES THERE AND I WANT TO AVOID THAT.**

Thanks for your time. Please help

Comment: The connection timeout is set via `conduit.getClient().setConnectionTimeout(...)`, is it what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only option is to create a spring configuration file that configures an http:conduit with a name of "http://servername.com/.*" that sets a shorter timeout.   Create the bus from that config file.   See:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html